# How to create variables dynamically using a loop

Tags: shell-script, variable

I have the following code in my bash script

```
d1=$(($t1-$t0))
d2=$(($t2-$t1))
d3=$(($t3-$t2))
d4=$(($t4-$t3))
d5=$(($t5-$t4))
d6=$(($t6-$t5))
d7=$(($t7-$t6))
d8=$(($t8-$t7))
```

If this goes on to `d=100` etc then obviously I need to use a loop to create these variable lines.

How would I dynamically generate this code with a
`for i in {1..n}; do done` loop
so that the `d1` through to `d100` values are generated and evaluate correctly?

eg with inputs before runnig loop
`t0=6; t1=10, t2=20`
outputs after running loop are
`echo $d1`
4
`echo $d2`
10

?

Comment: Why would you need this? It sounds like you should be using an array instead.

Comment: I've been trying it with a for next loop. How would you do it with an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *can* do what you ask for, that makes for unnecessarily complicated and hard to maintain code. I would suggest this alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

tArray=( 6 10 20 )

for((i=0; i<${#tArray[@]} -1; i++));
do
  dArray[i]=$((tArray[i+1] - tArray[i]))
done

for((i=0; i<${#dArray[@]}; i++));
do
  echo "${tArray[i+1]} - ${tArray[i]} = ${dArray[i]}"
done
```

Running that returns:

```
$ foo.sh
10 - 6 = 4
20 - 10 = 10
```

---

For reference, this is how you would do it using your original idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

t0=6
t1=10
t2=20

for i in {0..1}; do
  tVarName1=t${i}
  tVarName2=t$((i+1))
  dVarname=d${i}
  eval "$dVarname=$(( ${!tVarName2} - ${!tVarName1} ))"
done

echo "D0: $d0"
echo "D1: $d1"
```

Comment: no need for `$(( ))` inside `for (( .. ))`, it's already an arithmetic context, so `for ((i=0; i < ${#tArray[@]} - 1; i++ ))` should do. And no need for `${..}` around an array variable in an arithmetic context, so `$(( tArray[i+1] - tArray[i] ))` should do. (`${#var}` does need the dollar-braces though)

Comment: Thanks, @ilkkachu, fixed.